# Python Selenium Finding Element With Dynamic URL and Name with Little HTML

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

**Hey everyone!** Today I am working with Python 3 and Selenium web driver. I am encountering a problem with finding by element. Here is the HTML:

```
<a _ngcontent-pxc-c302="" class="name ng-star-inserted" href="/person/20d4a795d3fb43bdbee7e480df27b05b">michele regina</a>
```

The goal is to click on the first name that appears in a listed column.

The name changes with every page refresh. This comes with two problems in that the link text is the name and it changes, and the link constantly changes as well for each different name except for the part that says `/person/`

I tried the following:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.name ng-star-inserted").click()
```

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("name ng-star-inserted").click()
```

Which resulted in an element that is not a clickable error.
I also tried xpath by copying and pasting the entire XPath copied from Google inspector... lol

```
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/app-root/app-container/div/div/tc-app-view/div/div/div/ng-component/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/div/div[2]/tc-person-table-container/tc-collapse-expand[1]/section/tc-person-table/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/tc-person-table-cell/a').click()
```

and it kind of works sometimes, which is weird but I am sure there has to be a better way. Thank you so much in advance! Any help is appreciated! Also, I am very new to Python, I know zero HTML, and I am also newer to stack! Thanks!

Comment: Can you share a link to the web page?

Comment: No sorry, it's within login, and I can't give it away. But maybe I can get more of the HTML, would that be useful? I just don't know what to look for.

Comment: Sharing the entire page HTML, or at least big block of it may help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the given full xpath the `a` tag you are looking for is in `table`,`section`,`div`. Look for an id in those tags and trace the `a`.